# PHP - Read/Send parameters to a running programme (command line)

Tags: php, exe

I've been working on a webinterface for a game server deployment system. The game in question requires the user to enter their authentification key to allow the server to run in their name.

I can get the server to start using the exec() function however I need to be able to read the console output and allow the user to send things to the console via a php form.

I've tried looking around, google searches etc. If anyone could give me a hand with this I'd be very grateful.

The webserver is running XAMPP on Windows Server 2008 with up to date PHP etc.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: http://php.net/popen  and note that what you want is probably not possible. Remember that ever PHP request is a SEPARATE http connection, and every request your user makes would get a DIFFERENT process started.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you need [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function:

> **Return Values**
>
> The output from the executed command or NULL if an error occurred or
>   the command produces no output.

Example usage:

```
<?php
   $output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into this!